# Call MSXSL from batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, msxsl, forfiles

I want to create a batch file that loops through a folder containing xml files, then call msxsl to modify them and after modify the xml file, copying to another folder with original filename.

I tried this:

```
forfiles /p C:\Users\mae\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\In /m *.xml /c "cmd /c C:\Users\mae\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\msxsl.exe @file pre-process_add_filename.xsl -o C:\Users\mae\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\Out\@file"
```

But that gives me this error:

> ```
> Error occurred while creating file 'C:\Users\mae\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\Out\"bk_OIOUBLInvoice_TEST.xml"'.
>
>
> Code:   0x8007007b
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
> ```

This is because of the double quotes around the output filname. How do I get around this?

Comment: Don't use [tag:forfiles], use a [tag:for-loop] instead. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` to read the usage information and find out how it works.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by others in comments, you should use a standard [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) for your task rather than [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html):

```cmd
for %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\In\*.xml") do (
    "%UserProfile%\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\msxsl.exe" "%%I" "pre-process_add_filename.xsl" -o "%UserProfile%\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\Out\%%~nxI"
)
```

But if you do insist on `forfiles` you could use the following code:

```cmd
forfiles /P "%UserProfile%\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\In" /M "*.xml" /C "cmd /C for %%I in (@file) do 0x22%UserProfile%\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\msxsl.exe0x22 @file 0x22pre-process_add_filename.xsl0x22 -o 0x22%UserProfile%\Documents\Testing\MSXSL\Out\%%~I0x22"
```

The inner `for` loop together with the [`~`-modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) is used to get rid of the additional quotation marks around the file name returned by `@file`. The term `0x22` is `forfiles`-specific and marks a literal quotation mark.